# SQL Finding Duplicate Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am working on creating a query to find duplicates within a table. I have ID, customernumber and status columns.

The `Status` column can be either ('open') or ('closed'). What I am trying to accomplish is to create a query where I can see if the `ID` has been duplicated.

So the end result of the query will be one row that shows the `ID` as ('open') and the other row showing the ID as ('closed'). We know it's a duplicate because there can only be one `ID` that needs to be ('open').

Here is my code for looking at items that are ('open'), but I would like to verify if the same `customerid` has been ('closed').... Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    customerID, customernumber,
    COUNT(DISTINCT orderid)
FROM 
    test.dbo
WHERE
    Status IN ('open')
GROUP BY 
    Customerid, Customernumber
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT orderid) > 1
```

Comment: For all SQL related questions, a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below query,

Using Rank,

```
SELECT customerID, customernumber, status
from 
(SELECT
    customerID, customernumber, status,
    row_number() over(partition by customerID order by status) as rnk
FROM 
    test.dbo) T1 where rnk > 1;
```

Using Join

```
SELECT T1.* FROM test.dbo T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    customerID, COUNT(1)
FROM test.dbo GROUP BY Customerid HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) T2
on (T1.customerID = T2.customerID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Table Database SQL Server :

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    orderid varchar(25),
    CustomerID varchar(25),
    customernumber varchar(25),
    status char(1)
);
```

Insert data to table Customer (For Example) :

```
insert into Customer values 
('1','Cust001','888',0),
('2','Cust001','888',1),
('3','Cust002','888',0),
('4','Cust003','888',0),
('5','Cust004','888',0)
```

And you can use **Dense_Rank** to find which **CustomerID** has closed and still open. For example :

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition by CustomerID order by Status) as RowNum, CustomerID, customernumber,
CASE
    WHEN status = 0 THEN 'Open'
    ELSE 'Closed'
END 'Status'
FROM Customer
```

Result :

| RowNum | CustomerID | CustomerNumber | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cust001 | 888 | Open |
| 2 | Cust001 | 888 | Closed |
| 1 | Cust002 | 888 | Open |
| 1 | Cust003 | 888 | Open |
| 1 | Cust004 | 888 | Open |

Answer (score 0):

If this answer is not what you wanted, please edit your question and add sample data and expected result so it is more clear to us what exactly you are after.

If I understand you right, you just want to find rows with more than one time the same status per customer, correct ?
If so a very simple group by can do this,
check [this dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/homVVILm)

the query is just this

```
select t.customernumber, t.status, count(t.status) as NumberOfStatus
from   test t
group by t.customernumber, t.status
```

and it returns this

| customernumber | status | NumberOfStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | closed | 1 |
| 001 | open | 2 |
| 002 | open | 1 |

And just add a `having` to get only the doubles

```
select t.customernumber, t.status, count(t.status) as NumberOfStatus
from   test t
group by t.customernumber, t.status
having count(t.status) > 1
```

| customernumber | status | NumberOfStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | open | 2 |